# Diffusion with spatially variable coefficient and source

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, laplace-transform, heat-equation

I've carefully studied many resources (such as [1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X99000050), [2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022169409007173), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538678/diffusion-advection-equation-with-time-variable-coefficients), [4](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9863-7_697) and etc.) where they discuss different forms of diffusion equations. However, my specific equation was not studied in there. I'm hoping to get help on solving a diffusion equation with spatially variable coefficient and source, as follows (1D):

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}J=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(D\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} +E)$$
$$\sigma(x,0)=\sigma_0 \\
J(-L/2,t)=J_{-} \\
J(+L/2,t)=J_{+} $$

where $-L/2\leq x \leq L/2$ and, $D(x)$ and $E(x)$ are *only* spatially variable.

Separation of variables and Laplace's transforms are both welcome. Approximate form of solution with series analysis are highly appreciated.

---

**More details as requested:**

The original equation to solve is as follows ($-L/2\leq x \leq L/2$):

$$\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}J=B\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-\frac{D}{kT}eZ\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial x}+\frac{D}{kT}\frac{Q}{T}\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial x}-\frac{D}{kT}\Omega\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial x})$$
$$\sigma(x,0)=\sigma_0 \\
J(-L/2,t)=J_{-} \\
J(+L/2,t)=J_{+} $$

where

- Diffusivity: $D(x)=D_0e^{-\frac{E_a}{kT}}$ ☹️
- Voltage: $V(x)=-\rho j x$
- Temperature: $T(x)=T_0+T_m \big( 1-\cosh(\frac{L}{2\Gamma})\cosh(\frac{x}{\Gamma}) \big) +T_n \big( \sinh(\frac{L}{2\Gamma})\sinh(\frac{x}{\Gamma}) \big)$
- Mean hydro-static stress: $\sigma(x,t)$:

and constants are

- $B=3e10[Pa]$: Bulk modulus
- $k=1.38e-23[J/K]$: Boltzmann constant
- $e=1.6e-19[C]$: Electron charge
- $Z=1$: Charge number
- $Q=1.6e-19[J]$: Specific heat transfer
- $\Omega=1.66e-29[m^3]$: Atomic volume
- $D_0=7.56e-5[m^2/s]$ : Diffusion prefactor
- $E_a=1.6e-19[J]$ : Activation energy
- $\rho=1.67e-8[ohm.m]$ : Resistivity
- $T_0=\frac{T_-+T_+}{2}$ : Approx external temperature
- $T_n=\frac{T_--T_+}{2}$ : Ends Temperature diff
- $T_m=\frac{j^2\rho \Gamma^2}{k_{th}}$ : Max Temperature rise
- $\Gamma =6e-6[m] $ : Heating characteristic length
- $k_{th}=400[W/m.K]$ : Thermal conductance

**But really, you only need to know the following inputs** (roughly center ranges 
 added):

- $L\sim 100[um]$ : Wire length
- $j\sim 5e10[A/m^2]$ : Current density
- $T_-=T(x=-L/2)\sim373[K]$ : Fixed temperature at $-L/2$ end
- $T_+=T(x=+L/2)\sim373[K]$ : ixed temperature at $+L/2$ end
- $\sigma(x,0) = \sigma_0$

The original equation can be seen as:

$$\sigma_t=(C_1\frac{D}{T}+C_2\frac{D}{T^2}T_x+C_3\frac{D}{T}\sigma_x)_x$$

By further encapsulation, it can be seen as follows (similar to what mentioned in the question):

$$\sigma_t=(F\sigma_x)_x+E_x$$

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the introduction of suitable functions $u$ and $v$ such that $c = u + v$ and $u$ satisfies the non-homogeneous boundary conditions

\begin{align*}
x = -L/2: & \quad u_x = (J_o - E_o)/D_o, \\
x =  L/2: & \quad u_x = (J_L - E_L)/D_L,
\end{align*} where the subscripts for $D$, $J$ and $E$ indicate evaluation at the corresponding endpoint. The *easiest* function $u$ is $u(x) = \frac{1}{2} A ( x - B)^2$, where the constants $A$ and $B$ may be determined from the two conditions above.

Now, notice that the problem for $v$ is homogeneous in the spatial directions and given by

$$ v_t = ( D v_x)_x + Q(x), \quad -L/2 < x < L/2, $$

with BCs $v_x(-L/2,t) = v_x(L/2,t) = 0$ and IC $v(x,0) = c(x,0) - u(x)$. The source term is $Q(x) = (D u_x)_x + E_x$, which is also known.

Thanks to superposition, your problem has now homogeneous boundary conditions but contains a nonzero, in general, source term. You may find now nontrivial solutions for the problem with $Q = 0$ (eigenfunctions), and expand the solution to the problem in terms of these functions (basis).

Can you take it from here?

---

*Follow up:*

Let's consider for a moment the problem $w_t = (D w_x)_x$ with homogenous boundary conditions $w_x(-L/2,t) = w_x(L/2,t) = 0$. I don't care too much about the initial conditions for now. Since $D = D(x)$, the problem is separable and admits a combination of solutions of the form $w = X(x)T(t)$, where $X$ and $T$ are nonzero. Introduction of the ansatz yields

$$ X T' = T \, (D X')' \implies \frac{T'}{T} = \frac{1}{X} (D X')' = \lambda, $$ where the primes denote differentiation with respect the corresponding independent variable and $\lambda$ is a real (negative, positive or zero) constant. Now we need some information about $D$, since the shape of the final solution will strongly depend on the definition of $D$. Is it positive everywhere in the domain? Is it linear/quadratic/cubic...?

Note that the problem in $x$ is

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( D \frac{\mathrm{d}X}{\mathrm{d
 }x} \right) - \lambda X = 0, \quad -L/2 < x < L/2, \quad X'(-L/2) = X'(L/2) = 0, $$ where $\lambda$ is *a priori* unknown (it has to be chosen appropriately as an eigenvalue). This problem may not have an easy to obtain closed-form solution. For $D = 1$ (or any other positive constant) the solution take form of cosines and sines but for slightly more complicated choices of $D$ you arrive at Bessel, Airy, Legendre functions, etc.

If you give me a hint on what kind of $D$s you're trying to solve the problem for, I can elaborate on finding a basis for your eigenfunctions on your domain and expand $v$ in terms of this basis (the $w$ functions).

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I've been digesting your hint and trying to solve it by myself. I fixed the new BCs (please review my edit if they are indeed correct). My knowledge here is pretty basic. I'm trying my best but having hard time to match your current formulation, with any existing problems solved in my references mentioned above. Would you please carry on and derive the final answer? The sources I provided in the question might help you not to do all the work and save you some time. You're more than welcome to use them if they are actually helpful. Any effort is highly appreciated..

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen  Thanks for your review. I still think that the old BCs by excluding $D_0u_x+E_0-J_0$ and $D_Lu_x+E_L-J_L$ will result in having $D_0v_x(0,t)=D_Lv_x(L,t)=0$ not $v_x(0,t)=v_x(L,t)=0$. Can you please let me know why my conclusion is wrong?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what about you sir. Any comment?

Comment: Also any effort is highly appreciated.

Comment: Dear @JohnButler, I've been out of town these days. I'll provide a follow-up edit on my answer as soon as I can.

Comment: I found the solution for $c_t=(Dc_x)_x+E_x$ with the same ICs and BCs when $D$ and $E$ are NOT spatially variable (i.e. constant temperature in the original form). The solution is as follows:

$$c(x,t)=\frac{E}{D}L\{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{L}-4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos((2n+1)\pi \frac{x}{L})}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2\exp((2n+1)^2\pi^2\frac{Dt}{L^2})}\}$$

I'm hoping to find something like this for non-constant $D$ and $E$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for following up. I greatly appreciate your past and any future effort. I actually checked your profile and found out that you have a great background in mechanical engineering and its relevant mathematics (e.g. differential equations and calculus). So, I felt like I can release more details and background about my problem -- as it might be interesting to you or may give more insight. No need to mention that, any substantial work from you on finding a closed-form solution will be willingly cited in my paper.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your edit. Now we see where things come from. I'm surprised about the negative sign in front of some terms inside the x derivative. Unfortunately, I don't know if I will be in my office today, but I can try to look at it tomorrow in more detail. However, I'm not sure if the problem has a nice analytical solution, given the shape of your term multiplying d sigma/dx. Have you tried numerics? On the other hand, is there any interesting limit you want to study so you can use some asymptotics? Perhaps a nondimensional activation  energy is a large parameter here.

Comment: I use numerical methods to find out results (also FEM tools), yet I'm actually trying to to come up -if possible- with a closed-form, approximated series or any sort of formula that can be used effortlessly by semiconductor engineers. Currently the effect of temperature is ignore in this industry and what it mathematically means is, *diffusion and source are constant*. The solution of this problem exists (I provided in my previous comment).

Comment: Dear @JohnButler, after looking into your problem for a bit, I realise that it's going to be impossible for me to find a closed-form solution for your problem. The term $D\Omega/(kT)$ in front of $\partial_x \sigma$ is highly nonlinear in $x$ thereby complicating the analysis a great deal. I would be surprised if there exists an analytical solution for your such an expression for the diffusivity coefficient... However, I notice that the relative temperature changes are small. This can be quantified by the nondimensional parameter $\epsilon = T_m/T_0$...

Comment: Dear @JohnButler, after looking into your problem for a bit, I realise that it's going to be impossible for me to find a closed-form solution for your problem. The term $D\Omega/(kT)$ in front of $\partial_x \sigma$ is highly nonlinear in $x$ thereby complicating the analysis a great deal. I would be surprised if there exists an analytical solution for your such an expression for the diffusivity coefficient... However, I notice that the relative temperature changes are small. This can be quantified by the nondimensional parameter $\epsilon = T_m/T_0$...

Comment: ... Maybe you can compute an approximate solution for small values of $\epsilon$ using a regular asymptotic expansion of the form $\sigma =  \sigma_0 + \epsilon \sigma_1 + \ldots $, where $\sigma_0$ is the solution for $\epsilon = 0$ (leading order), which is readily available. Are you familiar with such an analysis?

Comment: I've been studying what you suggested since September 1. While very interesting things I found, it is not appropriate for my problem context. As I mentioned I'm trying to have a model to be used by software or electrical engineers. Hoping to find a sigma-based series or I do not know. Any update or thought? Thank you for your time  a lot.

Comment: A very similar and simpler question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447020/diffusion-heat-equation-with-spatially-variable-source). Can you please kindly take a look and share your thoughts on that? Thanks.

Comment: Dear @JohnButler, in their problem, the diffusion coefficient $k$ is a constant, thereby reducing the complexity by a lot. In that case, separation of variables yields simple constant-coefficient ODEs. In your problem, as I mentioned above, $D$ and $T$ are terribly nonlinear functions. I'd be happy to solve a similar but easier toy problem for you if you open a new post.

Comment: I have it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448770/diffusion-heat-equation-with-spatially-variable-source-incompatible-solutions) sir. It is indeed a lot easier.