# Diffusion/Heat equation with spatially variable source

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, laplace-transform, heat-equation

Many resources including but not limited to [1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X99000050), [2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022169409007173), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538678/diffusion-advection-equation-with-time-variable-coefficients), [4](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9863-7_697), [5](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1959chs..book.....C), [6](http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30345d/courses/engs43/chapter2.pdf), [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404471/diffusion-with-spatially-variable-coefficient-and-source)** discuss various forms of diffusion and heat equations under different conditions. However, the following specific formulation with a spatially variable source and inhomogeneous flux BCs was not studied in them:

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}J=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(k(\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} +S)) \quad \text{or} \quad c_t=k c_{xx}+k S_x$$
$$J(-L/2,t)=J_{-} \\
J(+L/2,t)=J_{+} \\
c(x,0)=c_0$$

where $-L/2\leq x \leq L/2$ and $S(x)$ is spatially variable.

I'm looking for a nice closed form or an (infinite series-based) analytic expression -- if possible. I have done some work by using the technique of Laplace transformations but could not get it done fully. Any help on the rest of my work is highly appreciated.

---

*Here is my attempt:*

1. **Transform inhomogeneous BCs to homogeneous BCs**

Introducing $u$ and $v$ such that $c = u + v$ and $u$ satisfies the non-homogeneous BCs, yields:

\begin{align*}
x = -L/2: & \quad u_x = (J_-/k) - S_- \\
x = +L/2: & \quad u_x = (J_+/k) - S_+
\end{align*}

where the subscripts for $J$ and $S$ indicate evaluation at the corresponding endpoint. An easy function $u$ is $u(x) = A x^2 + B x$, where $A=\frac{(J_+-J_-)-(S_+-S_-) k}{2kL}$ and $B=\frac{(J_++J_-)-(S_++S_-) k}{2k}$.

Now, the problem for $v$ is homogeneous and given by ($-L/2 < x < L/2$):

$$ v_t = kv_{xx} + Q(x) $$
$$v_x(-L/2,t) = v_x(+L/2,t) = 0 \\ v(x,0) = c_0 - u(x)$$

where the source term is $Q(x) = k (u_x + S)_x$ which is also known.

Thanks to superposition, the problem has now homogeneous BCs but contains a nonzero, in general, source term. I found the solution for the problem with $Q = 0$ and $0<x<L$ (**rather that** $-L/2<x<L/2$) which is as follows (I verified it with [5](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1959chs..book.....C)):

$$v=2\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}e^{-k\alpha_n^2t}\frac{\beta_n \cos(\alpha_n x)}{\alpha_n^2L/2}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)[\beta_n \cos(\alpha_n x)]dx+\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)dx$$

where $\beta_n=\alpha_n \cos(\alpha_n L/2)$ and $\alpha_n=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{L}$. Also $f(x)=c_0-u(x)$.

2. **Extending the solution to where there is $Q(x)$**

I was not able to convert the intervl from $0<x<L$ to $-L/2<x<L/2$ properly and expand the obtained solution to the original problem with a spatially variable source (i.e. $Q(x)$). A sanity check is also greatly appreciate as there might be some errors in my work.

---

** Essentially the question asked in [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404471/diffusion-with-spatially-variable-coefficient-and-source) is even a more general form of the current question. While I learned a lot from the discussion done in [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404471/diffusion-with-spatially-variable-coefficient-and-source), the questions remained unanswered (in a complete way). The main and intersting complication in [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404471/diffusion-with-spatially-variable-coefficient-and-source) was the varying diffusion coefficient rather than what is focused in current question. Special thanks to [dmoreno](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/121008/dmoreno) for providing fruitful discussions.

Comment: @dmoreno It would be great if I can have your thoughts on this.

Comment: Have you looked into Green's functions?

Comment: @eepperly16 I'm familiar with a very limited amount of experience. I'm usually not comfortable with Green's functions. While I will work on them, would you please add your work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have to solve
$$v_{t}-kv_{xx}=Q(x)$$
With
$$v_{x}(L/2, t)=v_{x}(-L/2, t)=0$$
$$v(x, 0)=f(x)$$
Let us expand the solution in terms of the von-Neumann functions
$$v(x, t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}v_{n}(t)\cos\Big(\frac{(2{n}+1)\pi{x}}{L}\Big)$$
Then
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\Big(\partial_{t}+\frac{k((2{n}+1)\pi)^{2}}{L^{2}}\Big)v_{n}(t)\cos\Big(\frac{(2{n}+1)\pi{x}}{L}\Big)=Q(x)$$
Then multiply by
$$\cos\Big(\frac{(2{m}+1)\pi{x}}{L}\Big)$$
and integrate on $[-L/2, L/2]$ to give
$$\Big(\partial_{t}+\frac{k((2{m}+1)\pi)^{2}}{L^{2}}\Big)v_{m}(t)=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}Q(x)\cos\Big(\frac{(2{m}+1)\pi{x}}{L}\Big)dx$$
The solution is found by the integrating factor technique
$$v_{m}(t)=c_{m}\exp\Big(-\frac{k((2{m}+1)\pi)^{2}t}{L^{2}}\Big)+\frac{L}{k((2{m}+1)\pi)^{2}}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}Q(x)\cos\Big(\frac{(2{m}+1)\pi{x}}{L}\Big)dx$$
And the constants $c_{m}$ is found from the condition
$$v_{m}(0)=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}f(x)\cos\Big(\frac{(2{m}+1)\pi{x}}{L}\Big)dx$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. That's pretty nice way of doing it. I just learned another way or maybe the same in principle from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoLweaiYG7g#t=455) and [here](http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_10.pdf), in which $Q$ is a function of $t$ and $x$. Yet, I still stuck with three questions: 

(1) I compared those solutions with yours (after omitting $t$), I left with an extra exponential term multiplying your last term in $v_m(t)$. Should not be an exponential term there?

Comment: (2) You used $cos$ rather than $sin$ in your von-Neumann functions. Is there any particular reason for that choice? Perhaps due to the symmetry of my problem (i.e. $-L/2<x<+L/2$ rather than $0<x<+L$)?

Any clarification is highly appreciated.

Comment: (3) I realized that the BCs are not used in your solution and also in the sources (I provided in my previous comments). Those sources showed that BCs are not useful. However, the BCs were Dirichlet and in my problem are Neumann. Are Neumann BCs also not useful? And why is that? I greatly appreciate if you can kindly edit your answer by addressing my questions. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448770/diffusion-heat-equation-with-spatially-variable-source-incompatible-solutions?noredirect=1&lq=1) and try to answer it as well.

Comment: The boundary conditions are used. They serve the reason of choosing $\cos$ functions of that specific form, they satisfy this conditions.

Comment: As far as I see, the solution you have and the one I do have are different in the single thing. That is your series has the terms $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ and mine has $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. I guess that your solution (choice of the range of $n$) is correct since $\cos$ is the even function and the negative $n$ does not give any new solutions. I.e. the functions $f_{n}(x)=\cos\Big(\frac{(2n+1)\pi{x}}{L}\Big)$ have the property $f_{-k}(x)=f_{k-1}(x)$. So those solutions with $n<0$ have not to be there.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I still cannot see  $\alpha_n \cos(\alpha_n L/2)$ (in $\beta_n$) in your. Am I missing anything here? How come a solution for $0<0<L$ is the same as $-L/2<x<L/2$?